# Execute BEACON method every 100 milliseconds in Android

Tags: android, runnable, ibeacon-android, estimote

I try do indoor navigation android application using Estimote beacons. Here is the code which I used to get distance between android device and beacons. This code sections runs approximately in every 1 second.

I need to execute this in every 100 milliseconds.

```
beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
  @Override public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {

        long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i("###################### ", " #################");
        Log.i("Time Class ", " Time value in millisecinds "+time);

        toolbar.setSubtitle("Found beacons: " + beacons.size());
        ArrayList<Beacon> newBeacons = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int x=0; x<beacons.size();x++) {
          int major= beacons.get(x).getMajor();
          int minor = beacons.get(x).getMinor();

          if (major==3&&minor==3) {
            newBeacons.add(beacons.get(x));
            Dsi[0] = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(x));
          }
          else if (major==4&&minor==4) {
            newBeacons.add(beacons.get(x));
            Dsi[1] = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(x));
          }
          else if (major==2&&minor==2) {
            newBeacons.add(beacons.get(x));
            Dsi[2] = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(x));
          }
        }

        double[][] positions = new double[][] { { -3.4, 0.8}, { 0, 7.5 }, { 6.7, 6.7 } };
        double[] distances = new double[] { Dsi[0], Dsi[1], Dsi[2] };

        TrilaterationFunction trilaterationFunction = new TrilaterationFunction(positions, distances);
        LinearLeastSquaresSolver lSolver = new LinearLeastSquaresSolver(trilaterationFunction);
        NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver nlSolver = new NonLinearLeastSquaresSolver(trilaterationFunction, new LevenbergMarquardtOptimizer());

        double[] expectedPosition = new double[] { 3.3, 15.0 };
        RealVector x = lSolver.solve();
        Optimum optimum = nlSolver.solve();
        testResults(expectedPosition, 1, optimum, x);
        adapter.replaceWith(newBeacons);

        time= System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.i("Time Class ", " Time value in millisecinds "+time);
        Log.i("###################### ", " #################");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You don't show what initiates the code shown.  When is this executed?  Why is it currently limited to 1 second?

Comment: Edited the code. I don't know the reason for time limited to 1 second. 
I need to execute this code in every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Apparently you are using Estimote's Android SDK. Apparently the clever minds at Estimote have come to the conclusion that a 1 second scan interval is optimal considering all the different factors like the advertising frequency of their beacons, people typically moving only 1 meter/second etc. Apparently their SDK is only available as an AAR library, so reverse engineering it is just a little bit more difficult but not impossible. But probably the license does not allow "hacking" it. I don't know. Probably somewhere in the `BeaconManager` class lies the secret to the scan frequency.

Comment: You can probably get a more educated answer [on their own forum](https://forums.estimote.com/c/android-sdk).

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen Thank you for the comment. I used timetask to do this. But It's not the solution for this. I need to decrease the scan interval into 100 milliseconds. Estimote Beacons' transmit power can be reduced to 100 milliseconds. I will follow this. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this problem. Here is the answer and explanation for the Estimote Beacon users and lovers.

There is a method called **setForegroundScanPeriod** in the Estimote Android SDK. This method implemented in **BeaconManager** class. This can be used to increase or decrease scanning time period.

This is the method definition

```
setForegroundScanPeriod(long scanPeriodMillis,long waitTimeMillis)
```

First parameter for the change the scan period and second parameter for the waiting time between two scanning period. Values of all parameters are taken as milliseconds. Example as follows.

```
setForegroundScanPeriod(200,5)
```

If you called like this, Then code section is executing in every 200 milliseconds with 5 milliseconds time interval.

Default values of the method is 1s for the scan time period and 0s  for the waiting period. **200ms** is minimum scan time period and **0ms** is minimum waiting period. (if you reduce the scanning period scanning period, Broadcasting interval of your Estimote Beacon should be reduced. Broadcasting interval should less than scan time period and also minimum Broadcasting interval is 100ms)

**Reducing Broadcast interval is negatively effect for Battery life of Beacon and Reducing scan time period is negatively effect for Battery life of Android device.**

Here is the full example which I used to scan Beacons.

```
BeaconManager beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);

beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(200,0);

beaconManager.setRangingListener(new BeaconManager.RangingListener() {
  @Override public void onBeaconsDiscovered(Region region, final List<Beacon> beacons) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {

        toolbar.setSubtitle("Found beacons: " + beacons.size());

        ArrayList<Beacon> newBeacons = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int x=0; x<beacons.size();x++) {
          int major= beacons.get(x).getMajor();
          int minor = beacons.get(x).getMinor();

          if (major==3&&minor==3) {
            newBeacons.add(beacons.get(x));
            Dsi[0] = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(x));
          }
          else if (major==4&&minor==4) {
            newBeacons.add(beacons.get(x));
            Dsi[1] = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(x));
          }
          else if (major==2&&minor==2) {
            newBeacons.add(beacons.get(x));
            Dsi[2] = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacons.get(x));
          }
        }

        adapter.replaceWith(newBeacons);
      }
    });
  }
});
```